# How to exit shell which was opened within script?

Tags: shell-script, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm writing scripts to automate the installation and configuration of my raspberry pi. My problem is that the official installation script of [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) opens a new shell - the zsh. So that practically ends my script and i need a separate script for further configuration. I want my script to continue after the [omz](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) install.sh has finished.

**script:**

```
. ./functions.sh
echo "\n###### install zsh ######\n"


log "apt-get install -qqy zsh"

read -p "Enter Your Name: "  username
log "chsh -s /bin/zsh $username"

# this install.sh opens zsh and blocks proceeding of script
su - $username -c 'sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"

# I want the script to continue here
echo "More commands"
```

**Notes:**

- log is declared in functions.sh and will execute command and output command which was executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `RUNZSH` to no before running the installer, or run it with standard input not connected to a terminal, it won’t run the shell. In your case, adding `< /dev/null` at the end of the command feels like the simplest solution:

```
su - $username -c 'sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)" < /dev/null'
```

Comment: Thanks, that works :) So with `<  /dev/null` the standard input is connected  to `/dev/null` which is not a terminal and therefore the shell won't run?

Comment: Yes, the script [explicitly checks that its standard input is a terminal](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/702a594df3b49f40496e4840cae2d93c83d5bc4d/tools/install.sh#L208) and disables two features if it isn’t: running `chsh` itself, and running `zsh` at the end of the installation process.